# Search list using linq dynamically

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create a function where I can run dynamic linq queries.

Instead of creating a separate linq query for every search, I want to create one dynamic function, where I can pass the column name, I want to search.

So far, my dynamic linq query returns the string value in the search parameter, and I cannot reach the ID in the list

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Author> authors = new List<Author>
            {
                new Author {Id = 1, Name = "Mahesh Chand", Book = "ADO.NET Programming", Price = 49.95},
                new Author {Id = 2, Name = "Neel Beniwal", Book = "Jump Ball", Price = 19.95},
                new Author {Id = 3, Name = "Chris Love", Book = "Practical PWA", Price = 29.95}
            };
            // Add more items to the list  
            authors.Add(new Author { Id = 4, Name = "Jack", Book = "Graphics with GDI+", Price = 49.95});
            authors.Add(new Author { Id = 5, Name = "Jack", Book = "Mastering C#", Price = 54.95});
            authors.Add(new Author { Id = 6, Name = "Jack", Book = "Jumpstart Blockchain", Price = 44.95});

            var nameFound = SearchColumn(authors, "Name", "Jack");

        }

        public class Author
        {
            public int Id;
            public string Name;
            public string Book;
            public double Price;
        }
        public class MatchFound
        {
            public int Id;
            public string Column;
            public string MatchString;
        }

        private static List<MatchFound> SearchColumn(List<Author> authorList, string column, string searchCharacter)
        {
            var result = new List<MatchFound>();
            // linq query #1
            var separaList = authorList.Select(l => column).ToList();
            foreach (var row in separaList)
            {
                if (row == searchCharacter)
                {
                    var temp = new MatchFound()
                    {
                        Id = row.Id, // cannot reach ID, because linq Query #1 does not include ID
                        Column = column,
                        MatchString = row
                    };

                    result.Add(temp);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to go a different way, here is how you can use `Expression` trees to build a lambda method for the `Where` method:

```
static List<MatchFound> SearchColumn(List<Author> authorList, string column, string searchCharacter) {
    // a
    var aParm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Author), "a");
    // a.{column}
    var aColumnExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(aParm, column);
    // a.{column} == searchCharacter
    var whereLambdaBody = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, aColumnExpr, Expression.Constant(searchCharacter));
    // a => a.{column} == searchCharacter
    var whereLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Author, bool>>(whereLambdaBody, aParm);
    var whereFn = whereLambda.Compile();

    return authorList.Where(whereFn).Select(a => new MatchFound { Id = a.Id, Column = column, MatchString = searchCharacter }).ToList();
}
```

NOTE: Compilation of the `whereLambda` is slow, it would pay to cache the result if you were doing this a lot, Reflection with `GetValue` is probably faster until `authorList` is quite large. However, this method also works with LINQ to databases by just not compiling the `whereLambda` and instead passing the `Expression` into `Where`.

Answer (score 1):

`var separaList = authorList.Select(l => column).ToList();` this code is not good, because you are selecting what have you send to the function, if you are sending `Name` will select six times `Name` or if you are sending `Other` will select six times `Other`.

If i undertand correctly, you can achieve this by using [*Reflection*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection), so the function `SearchColumn` will be like :

```
private static List<MatchFound> SearchColumn(List<Author> authorList, string column, string searchCharacter)
{
    // linq query #1
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(Author).GetField(column, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    return authorList
        .Where(a => fieldInfo.GetValue(a).ToString() == searchCharacter)
        .Select(a => new MatchFound
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            Column = column,
            MatchString = searchCharacter
        }).ToList();
}
```

NOTE : if you change `Author` fields to properties, use [GetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty?view=net-5.0) instead [GetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfield?view=net-5.0).

For test :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Author> authors = new List<Author>
    {
        new Author {Id = 1, Name = "Mahesh Chand", Book = "ADO.NET Programming", Price = 49.95},
        new Author {Id = 2, Name = "Neel Beniwal", Book = "Jump Ball", Price = 19.95},
        new Author {Id = 3, Name = "Chris Love", Book = "Practical PWA", Price = 29.95}
    };
    // Add more items to the list  
    authors.Add(new Author { Id = 4, Name = "Jack", Book = "Graphics with GDI+", Price = 49.95 });
    authors.Add(new Author { Id = 5, Name = "Jack", Book = "Mastering C#", Price = 54.95 });
    authors.Add(new Author { Id = 6, Name = "Jack", Book = "Jumpstart Blockchain", Price = 44.95 });

    var nameFound = SearchColumn(authors, "Name", "Chris Love");
    Console.WriteLine($"Id : {nameFound.First().Id}");

    var bookFound = SearchColumn(authors, "Book", "Mastering C#");
    Console.WriteLine($"Id : {bookFound.First().Id}");
}
```

**Result**

```
Id : 3
Id : 5
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: I like to use `GetPropertyOrField` and an extension method on `MemberInfo`: `object GetValue(this MemberInfo ...)` that handles either.

Comment: I have a feeling you are correct, but I cannot figure out how to use GetProperty when I change the fields to properties

Comment: @InternetEngineer it's like `PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(Author).GetProperty(column, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    `